# Missing Removable Storage Manager Feature

Tags: windows, backup, restore

Anyone know a workaround for the instructions found here: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=4220 since they are incorrect for Windows Standard 2008 R2 SP1. There is no "Removable Storage Manager" feature available!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the kb related to the Server 08 R2/Windows 7 version of the ntbackuprestore utility.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/974674